# How to combine the lists that content_tag_for gives?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently using content_tag_for to give ids for elements of a list. The problem is the list is of 2 different models so content_tag_for is returning 2 separate lists. Is there a parameter for content_tag_for which combines the two?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, but you could concatenate the two arrays and pass them as the second `single_or_multiple_records` argument.

```
<%= content_tag_for(:tr, @cats + @dogs) do |pet| %>
  <td><%= pet.name %></td>
  <td><%= pet.owner %></td>
  <% if pet.responds_to?(:tricks) %>
  <td><%= pet.tricks.join(', ') %></td>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312713/merge-and-interleave-two-arrays-in-ruby if you want to interleave the two arrays instead

Comment: Whats the exact error? Are you sure that you are dealing with two collections or arrays and not an array and model instance?