# Order an array in an alternating pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting

I have an array of hashes:

```
[ 
  {item0: 1.0, item1: 0.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 0.0}
]
```

I want to be able to sort the array so that `item1` alternates between 1.0 and 0.0. There will be the same number of 1s and 0s.

How could that be done?

`array.sort_by{|x| x[item1]}` does not get the desired output.

The desired output is:

```
[ 
  {item0: 1.0, item1: 0.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 0.0},
  {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0}
]
```

Comment: This is not a duplicate of that question. I do not want them in sorted order. I want them to alternate.

Comment: @Iceman yes there will be the same number of 1.0s and 0.0s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This I believe will give you what you want.

```
data = [{item0: 1.0, item1: 0.0},
        {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0},
        {item0: 0.0, item1: 1.0},
        {item0: 0.0, item1: 0.0}]

zeros, ones = data.partition{ |i| i[:item1] == 0 }

# This does the same
# ones   = data.select { |x| x[:item1] == 1 }
# zeros = data.select { |x| x[:item1] == 0 }

ones.zip(zeros).flatten.compact
```

Got the idea from this [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312713/merge-and-interleave-two-arrays-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

```
 evens, odds = my_array.partition{|i| i[:item1] == 0 }
 alternating = []
 max = [evens.size, odds.size].max
 t = 0
 while t < max + 1
    alternating << evens[t] unless evens[t].nil?
    alternating << odds[t] unless odds[t].nil?
    t += 1
 end

alternating
```

If there is a large difference in size the above should group all the remaining value at the end. If that’s not what you want then change max to min.